# Constrained optimization using function of function

Tags: optimization, constraints

Suppose I have the following constrained optimization problem

$$max \quad f(x) \quad s.t. \quad g(x)=a$$

whose solution is denoted by $x^{*}$. I want to prove that this is the solution to the above mentioned proble in a diffferent way.

So let's consider the new function $z(g(x))$, which is logically equivalent to the initial $f(x)$ and has the same $x$ that maximizes it, but it has just be re-arranged to express the problem as a function of $g(x)$ instead of $x$ so that we could incorporate the effect of the constraint.

Assume that we take the derivative of $z(g(x))$ with respect to $g(x)$ and set it equal to $0$ ($\frac{\delta z}{\delta g} =0$ ) to find the optimal $g(x)$. Under the optimum I have the condition $g(x)-b=0$. If I now substitute the solution of the initial constrained problem $x^{*}$ into the expression above, I find that $g(x^{*})=a=b$. Is that enough to prove that $x^{*}$ is the optiumum for the intial constrained problem?

**In other words, can I re-express an optimization problem like 
$$max \quad f(x) \quad wrt \quad x \quad st \quad g(x)=a$$
as a new optimization problem 
$$max \quad z(g(x)) \quad wrt \quad g(x) \quad st \quad g(x)=a$$
so that i can put $\frac{\delta z}{\delta g} =0$ find the expression for the optimal $g(x)$ like $g(x)-b=0$ and later solve $g(x)-b$ for $x$ to find the optimal $x^{*}$ (provided that $x^{*}$ is such that $g(x^{*})=a$)?**

**Basic example: consider the minimization of the function $y=f(x)=(x-2)^{2}$ st $(x-2)^{0.5}>=0$, which is minimized for x=2. Then put g(x)=(x-2)^{0.5} and rewrite z(g(x))=(g(x)^{2})^{2}=g(x)^{4}: the g(x) that minimizes z(g(x)) is 0. Now remember that g(x)=(x-2)^{0.5}, therefore solving g(x)=0 for x gives x=2, which indeed is the optimum for the original problem**

Clearly proving that it is NOT right to do so is equivalent to proving that there exist cases where solving g(x)=a=b (or, for inequality constraints, g(x)=b>=a) for x gives results that are different from the optimal x for the initial constrained problem

Comment: So are you asking something like “maximizing a function f subject to a constraint expressed like g(x)=a is analogous to maximizing an “equivalent” function z(g(x)) wrt g(x), find the optimal condition g(x)-b=0 and then solve g(x)-b=0 for x provided that the optimal x* should be such that  g(x*)=a” ?

Comment: Yes, I am asking: if that happens, can we say that x* is the solution to the constrained optimization?

Comment: If you were able to find `z(g(x))=f(x)` then the solution is trivial: `max f(x) = z(a)`. 
Probably you might want to rephrase your question?

Comment: @ArseniyZhizhelev thanks for your help. I have edited (see the edited part in bold) so that the question may be a bit more explanatory

Comment: The problem $\frac{\delta z}{\delta g}=0$ looks irrelevant to the original problem. In the first problem you are looking for a point $x$ that belongs to $g(x) - a =0$. While in the variation problem you look for a function $g(x)$ that will be optimal in some sense, and not equal to $a$, generally speaking.
BTW, did you check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier ?

Comment: Yes yes, I know the Lagrange multiplier, but this is a reformulation of a more complex problem in matrix form that I have to solve analytically and do not want to solve analytically using lagrangian for the obvious reason that those gradients are troubling

Comment: So I was just trying to simplifying everything by using a function of a function ad saying: if I know that z(g(x)) is maximized at g(x)=b=a then solving  g(x)=b for x allows to find the optimal x to the original problem

Comment: The concept works for example like this: consider the function y=1/(x+2), which is maximized for x=-2. Then put the denominator x+2=g(x) and rewrite z(g(x))=1/g(x): the g(x) that maximizes z(g(x)) is 0. Now remember that g(x)=x+2, therefore solving g(x)=0 for x gives x=-2, which indeed is the optimum for the original problem. But here we have the unconstrained functions clearly

Comment: I have trouble with "wrt $g(x)$" which says $g(x)$ is acting as an independent variable and "$g(x) = a$" which says it is not; it's a constant function.

Comment: @JMallin : If you have a complete example of what you intend, I suggest adding that to your question -- an example can be worth many thousand words of description.

Comment: the function $y=1/(x+2)$ doesn't have maximum, as far as I can tell. It's undefined at $x=-2$.

Comment: @EricTowers thanks for your interest and suggestion. You're right indeed I used an example in yesterday editing, but now I substituted it with a more precise example including the constraint. let me know if you think the reasoning is right/wrong. thanks

Comment: @ArseniyZhizhelev ok it's good to be mathematically correct, but here I just used that example with the function going to +infinite because to me it could explain the underlying problem very easily and in a concise way. Anyway, I have now provided a new example on the minimization side adding the effect of an inequality constraint